# What is the "global parameter" in a Logic Pro Midi script?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

The [documentation for Logic Pro Midi](https://support.apple.com/guide/logicpro/use-the-scripter-lgce728c68f6/mac) says rather cryptically "The Scripter plug-in has one global parameter." But it doesn't say what that global parameter is.
What is it? And is it global within the instrument, or within all scripts running in all instruments in a particular song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is Global Parameters?

Global Parameters is a wrapper (of sorts) that displays the Script Editor interface which, in turn, is used to create your own MIDI processing plug-ins using [Scripter (JavaScript) API](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/logicpro/lgce3905a48c/mac).

All GUI enabled user defined controls are displayed below the Global Parameters as 'Script Parameters'

[image]

### Is it global within the instrument, or within all scripts running in all instruments in a particular song?

> The script has a channel strip specific scope

The Global Parameter opens the same Script editor and hence has a global scope (will run the same script in exactly the same way across Logic) BUT the user written script has a channel strip specific scope i.e. when the script on a channel strip is run, it will affect the components of that specific channel strip only.

---

Comment: Thanks! That's a bit of a bummer, and limits what the scripting can be used for. Future Apple developers reading this -- it would be cool if instruments could share info through scripts and code in one instrument could affect another.

Comment: Just curious - what 'info' do you want instruments to share? MIDI data? and how do you want one instrument to affect another?

Comment: So instruments driven by a shared midi track can "coordinate". Like in a jazz band how different instruments take turn soloing.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want multiple instruments to play the same MIDI data. This can be done in 2 ways - 1. using track aliases 2. creating multi-layered instruments using Track Stack (Summing).

Comment: I have a lot of ideas but this is among them.